# Entity Framework code-first on SQL Server and Postgres

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, postgresql, data-annotations

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application with need to connect to SQL Server and Postgres, depending on the server I'm running. It means that the same code that run on Postgres must run on SQL Server.

How can I do it without the need of refactor my data annotations on every publish?

I mean, explicitly, this configuration:

[image]

If I keep it, I can't run in SQL Server, if I remove it, I can't run on Postgres.

Is there any workaround for it?

Answer (score -1):

You can write an interface called `ILink` and then implement two class of link from it, use one of it for SQL Server and use the other for Postgres